# Extracting rows defined by several factors with a large number of levels

Tags: r, performance, dataframe, aggregate, grouping

### What I would like to do

I have a data frame with several grouping factors and some other data. I would like to group the rows according to those factors and flag or extract all rows which belong to groups with more than one member.

### The problem/question

I was able to come up with a solution (see example below) but the solution is not practical due to an inefficiency of `interaction()`. Even though `drop = TRUE` the running time of `interaction()` increases dramatically when the number of levels increases. Ultimately I would like to process 10 - 20 factors with up to 50'000 levels on a data.frame with a few hundred thousand rows.

Questions: 1) What is the most efficient approach to this problem? ("Efficient" measured in this order by execution time, memory requirement and readability of code)

Question 2) What is wrong with `interaction()`?

### The example

```
# number of rows
nobs <- 100000
# number of levels
nlvl <- 5000

#create two factors with a decent number of levels
fc1 <- factor(sample.int(nlvl, size = nobs, replace = TRUE))
fc2 <- factor(sample.int(nlvl, size = nobs, replace = TRUE))
#package in a data.frame together with some arbitrary data
wdf <- data.frame(fc1, fc2, vals = sample.int(2, size = nobs, replace = TRUE))
#just for information: number of unique combinations of factors, i.e. groups
ngroups <- nrow(unique(wdf[,1:2]))
print(ngroups)

#granular grouping, tt has nobs elements and ngroups levels
tt <- interaction(wdf[,1:2], drop = TRUE)

#grpidx contains for each row the corresponding group (i.e. level of tt)
#observe that length(grpidx) == nobs and max(grpidx) == ngroups
grpidx <- match(tt, levels(tt))
#split into list of groups (containing row indices)
grplst <- split(seq_along(grpidx), grpidx)
#flag groups with more than one member
flg_dup <- vapply(grplst, FUN = function(x)length(x)>1, FUN.VALUE = TRUE)
#collect all row indices of groups with more than one member
dupidx <- unlist(grplst[flg_dup])
#select the corresponding rows
nonunqdf <- cbind(grpidx[dupidx], wdf[dupidx,])
```

Timing of the line `tt <- interaction(wdf[,1:2], drop = TRUE)`

- nlvl == 500: 82 milliseconds
- nlvl == 5000: 28 seconds
- nlvl == 10000: 233 seconds

Comment: `library(data.table); setDT(wdf)[, if (.N > 1) c(g = .GRP, .SD), by=.(fc1, fc2)]` is fairly fast. This is a pretty common question.. going to search...

Comment: Here's one: http://stackoverflow.com/q/32259620/ I don't think it's a duplicate, though, since you're asking about performance here.

Comment: Even more pertinent: This (stackoverflow.com/q/32259620) is about a *single* factor, my problem are the multiple or joint factors.

Comment: Actually, the single vs multiple factor thing doesn't matter as much as you might think in terms of good approaches to this problem. `duplicated(x, by=c("col1","col2"))`, `ave(x, col1, col2, FUN = length)`, `group_by(col1, col2)` ...

Comment: I see where you are coming from but it was killing my approach. And BTW, I tried the magic one-liner above. My conclusion: lightning fast and works as advertised! The only thing left it seems, is to understand what the line actually means.

Comment: Ok cool, I'll post it and try to explain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using data.table (with example size `nobs = 1e5; nlvl = 5e3` as in the OP)...

```
library(data.table)
setDT(wdf) # convert to data.table in place

system.time(
  res <- wdf[, if (.N > 1) c(g = .GRP, .SD), by=.(fc1, fc2)]
)
# 0.04 seconds
```

`DT[i, j, by]` means "filter by `i`, group by `by`, then do `j`".

So in this case we are

1. grouping by `fc1, fc2`
2. counting rows in each group, `.N`
3. if there are enough rows, returning group counter `.GRP` along with the subset of data, `.SD`

See `?data.table` for general coverage of the notation and `?.N` regarding the special symbols.

I recommend visiting [the website](http://r-datatable.com) and going through the vignettes to start with the package.

---

*Alternatives.* This way retains the original row ordering:

```
system.time(res2 <- wdf[, `:=`(g = .GRP, n = .N), by=.(fc1, fc2)][n > 1L])
# 0.06 seconds
```

And this base R way fails:

```
system.time(res3 <- wdf[ave(vals, fc1, fc2, FUN = length) > 1])
# causes R to freeze while eating all my RAM... 
# probably because of too many factor combos
```